# restrict calendar based on week

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar

I use calendar .i want to restrict calendar when user select the date then date selection must be on weekly basic how i do that? days may be random e.g. Monday to Sunday or Tuesday to Monday etc .. must be 7 days

code

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

      $(function() {
  var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();
  var currentMonth = (new Date).getMonth();
  var currentDay = (new Date).getDate();

  $("#fromdate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date((currentYear - 1), 12, 1),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay)
  });
  $("#todate").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date((currentYear - 1), 12, 1),
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay)
  });
});
    </script>
```

HTML

```
 <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="From Date"></asp:Label>

  <input  ID="fromdate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />

 <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="To Date"></asp:Label>

  <input  ID="todate" runat="server" ClientIDMode="static" />
```

Comment: Can you place your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Give me the datepicker plugin url u using

Comment: this is which i using                                                                             <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
$(function() {
      var currentYear = (new Date).getFullYear();  
      $('#fromdate').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: new Date((currentYear + 1), 12, 1),
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {

            // Start Date
            var startDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#todate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', startDate);
            $('#todate').datepicker('setDate', startDate);

            // End Date
            var enddate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            enddate.setDate(enddate.getDate()+ 6);
            $('#todate').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', enddate);
      }});

      $('#todate').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        maxDate: '+6'
    });

});
```

Comment: I spent more time on this, looking forward for your reply

Comment: yes it works.. but the logic i apply on question is gone which is " now year is 2016 so i don't want past years and future years only want current year ... and also month is June or any other month so i don't want future months only want current and past months . when year 2017 then in calendar must be year 2017 ..when month is June or any other month then not able to select future months .. we only select  current month and past months according to year 
e,g, current month is June so
Jan 2016.... June 2016

Comment: so with that answer which you posted how i apply my previous logic ? in short  i dont want future years and past years.. and only want current year and dont want months also only want current month and past months i.e. now 2016 year so months in calendar must be jan 2016-june 2016 and with that also i want that 7 days selection